# How to pass different ViewModels to a generic method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project written in C# MVC 5. There are several Controllers/Views that perform a similar set of functions based on `<input ...` fields in the Razor View.

There's currently logic in each controller to save input field values to a database table and later allow these saved input values to be retrieved and the View's input fields are populated by them.

These Views have many similarities and so several of their fields are duplicated across these Models.

It's become difficult to maintain code in each controller that saves its own fields and I want to use generics to create a single, common routine that saves the values for any of these controllers.

For example, 2 simple ViewModels:

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Unique1 { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ViewModel2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Unique2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Database model used:

```
public class SavedInputs
{
        [Key] public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? Unique1 { get; set; }
        public int? Unique2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a function that can save either ViewModel's fields. Something like:

```
public bool SaveToDb(T model)
{
    var inputs = new SavedInputs()
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Unique1 = model.Unique1,
        Unique2 = model.Unique2
    }

    _db.SavedInputs.Add(inputs);

    ...
}
```

Then from each controller's Save action:

```
public ActionResult SaveInputs(ViewModel1 model)
{
    var success = SaveToDb(model);
}
```

Of course ... SaveToDb() above isn't going to work but hopefully it shows what I'm wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Why you are making seperate view model for each controller / view , make generic viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to do this.

Either you could have a common interface or abstract class that all your view models share which have the properties you want to save. Then `SaveToDb` just takes the interface instead of the generic type. Then in `SaveToDb` you can access all the properties of the interface properties from the model passed in and do whatever you want with them. I guess if you want to just have some properties null then abstract class makes sense, since you can override whatever you want to use
e.g.

```
public abstract class SavedInputsBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Unique1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int Unique2 { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel1 : SavedInputsBase
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override int Unique1 { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ViewModel2 : SavedInputsBase
{
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override int Unique2 { get; set; }
    ...
}

public bool SaveToDb(SavedInputsBase model)
{
    var inputs = new SavedInputs()
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Unique1 = model.Unique1,
        Unique2 = model.Unique2
    }

    _db.SavedInputs.Add(inputs);
}
```

Alternatively you could use something like Automapper nuget package and have `SaveToDb` take `SavedInputs` and then just map your viewmodel to `SavedInputs`. Or just manually map it everywhere you want to call SaveToDb.

Comment: Also, I meant to add... this is not a use-case for generics. To be able to access any properties of a generic arguement you need to supply a generic constraint on some interface or base class. In this case it makes sense to just pass the interface or base class directly